# What is the purpose of "if False:" here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, type-hinting, mypy

https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade/blob/fecacc91e57c224a0bd2564579ef01238650126c/pyupgrade.py#L53

```
if False:  # pragma: no cover (mypy)
    from typing import Type
    if sys.version_info >= (3,):
        AsyncFunctionDef = ast.AsyncFunctionDef
    else:
        AsyncFunctionDef = ast.stmt
```

The commit is not revealing:
https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade/commit/fecacc91e57c224a0bd2564579ef01238650126c#diff-8213eba6a28bcc759225cd8cf49b2fd1

`False` can be truthy in Python 2 (where it can be re-defined) but not in Python 3. It might be a joke, or work in progress, or way of commenting out the code, but this is quite a mature tool- am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `AsyncFunctionDef` is never needed at runtime, only by `mypy` in two Python-2-compatible type hints (at lines 1298 and 1318). The `if False` prevents the assignments from occurring at run-time, but lets `mypy` see the correct underlying type to use during type-checking. (It also prevents an `ImportError` from being raised at the attempt to import the `typing` module under Python 2.)

It would be clearer to use `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` (whose value is `False` at run-time, but `True` when `mypy` runs) here, except `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` is *also* unavailable in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very familar with `mypy`, I can see they recommend using `MYPY = False` where `TYPE_CHECKING` is not available https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html  so `mypy` considers `False` to be truthy when type checking?

Comment: `MYPY = False` ensures that when the code is actually executed, you'll skip things guarded by `if MYPY:...`. When `mypy` runs, it *interprets* certain conditionals without actually *evaluating* the Python code. The name `MYPY` is special-cased to be *assumed* `True`, regardless of its actual value.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that the `MYPY` variable has a special meaning to `mypy`? If yes, why is `if False:` type checked? Or are you saying that `mypy` type checks every line regardless of whether it's executed at runtime

Comment: Yes, `mypy` type-checks all code; it doesn't make any assumptions about run-time semantics like "will this condition be true", precisely *because* it needs to follow imports that may or may not be reached at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

`if False` is used over `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` because python3.5.0-3.5.2 is supported by pyupgrade and does not have `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` -- you can find more information in [flake8-typing-imports](https://github.com/asottile/flake8-typing-imports) (I'm also the author of this flake8 plugin)

in 3.5.3+ and the `typing` backport (available in anything <3.5) `TYPE_CHECKING` is available

disclaimer: I'm the author of pyupgrade